# Two keys in ~/.ssh directory

Tags: ssh

I originally had a DSA public key in my ~/.ssh directory on my server `id_dsa.pub`. The corresponding private key `id_dsa` is stored on my local machine.

I then generated an RSA key pair directly inside the ~/.ssh directory on my server which now contains `id_dsa.pub`, `id_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa`.

Shortly after, I found myself unable to execute any bash commands. Commands such as `ls` and `pwd` were returning command not found.

I then terminated the ssh session and tried to reconnect. However, now I am getting Permission denied (publickey). What happens when you have both rsa and dsa keys in ~/.ssh directory, do either keys work or does the rsa key supercede the dsa key?

Comment: Either key would work. Whatever problem you're having is unrelated to the keys. This is evident in that bash commands in your original session wouldn't care about the keys. Perhaps a disk failure on the server.

Comment: Thanks. Quite a coincidence that both happened at the same time. My initial thought was that there was some kind of security mechanism that forced a logout, kind of like when you change a password on a website.

Comment: Show the output of `ssh -v server`. Is your /home on the server mounted from elsewhere?

Comment: pastebin.com/asgd1Z9q. nope /home is on the same HDD as the root